# Concatenate all rows of a large csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, nltk, python-multiprocessing

So I have a large csv file (5 million rows) with multiple columns. Of particular interest to me is a column which contains text.

The input csv is of the following format:

***system_id, member_name,  message, is_post***

*0157e407,member1011, "I have had problems with my lungs for years now. It all started with an infection...", false*

*1915d457, member1055, "Looks like a lot of people take Paracetamol for managing pain and....",false*

The column 'message' contains text and is of interest.

Now the task is to concatenate all the rows of this column into a one single large text, and then compute n-grams (n=1,2,3,4,5) on it. The output should be 5 different files corresponding to n-grams in the following format:
For eg:

**bigram.csv**

***n-gram, count***

*"word1 word2", 7*

*"word1 word3", 11*

**trigram.csv**

***n-gram, count***

"word1 word2 word3", 22

*"word 1 word2 word4", 24*

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv
import re
import sys

import nltk


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print "%d Arguments Given : Exiting..." % (len(sys.argv)-1)
        print "Usage: python %s <inp_file_path>" % sys.argv[0]
        exit(1)
    ifpath = sys.argv[1]
    with open(ifpath, 'r') as ifp:
        reader = csv.DictReader(ifp)
        all_msgs = []
        fieldnames = reader.fieldnames
        processed_rows = []
        for row in reader:
            msg = row['message']
            res = {'message': msg}
            txt = msg.decode('ascii', 'ignore')
            # some preprocessing
            txt = re.sub(r'[\.]{2,}', r". ", txt)
            txt = re.sub(r'([\.,;!?])([A-Z])', r'\1 \2', txt)
            sentences = nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(txt.strip())
            all_msgs.append(' '.join(sentences))
    text = ' '.join(all_msgs)

    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    tokens = [token.lower() for token in tokens if len(token) > 1]
    bi_tokens = list(nltk.bigrams(tokens))
    tri_tokens = list(nltk.trigrams(tokens))
    bigrms = []
    for item in sorted(set(bi_tokens)):
        bb = OrderedDict()
        bb['bigrams'] = ' '.join(item)
        bb['count'] = bi_tokens.count(item)
        bigrms.append(bb)

    trigrms = []
    for item in sorted(set(tri_tokens)):
        tt = OrderedDict()
        tt['trigrams'] = ' '.join(item)
        tt['count'] = tri_tokens.count(item)
        trigrms.append(tt)

    with open('bigrams.csv', 'w') as ofp2:
        header = ['bigrams', 'count']
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(ofp2, header)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(bigrms)

    with open('trigrams.csv', 'w') as ofp3:
        header = ['trigrams', 'count']
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(ofp3, header)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(trigrms)

    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    fourgrams = nltk.collocations.QuadgramCollocationFinder.from_words(tokens)
    quadgrams = []
    for fourgram, freq in fourgrams.ngram_fd.items():
        dd = OrderedDict()
        dd['quadgram'] = " ".join(fourgram)
        dd['count'] = freq
        quadgrams.append(dd)
    with open('quadgram.csv', 'w') as ofp4:
        header = ['quadgram', 'count']
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(ofp4, header)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(quadgrams)
```

This has been running for past 2 days on a 4 core machine. How can I make this more efficient (using pandas and/or multiprocessing, perhaps) and speed it up as reasonably as possible?

Comment: Have you used print statements to figure out what the bottleneck is?

Comment: First thing. You should consider saving processed input file. When you generate big `text` list, save it to file for later processing.

Check out how long it takes and if it takes reasonable time profile ngrams calculation.

Comment: Upload a small part of your csv file and the desired output out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a few changes:

## Find the bottleneck

What portion is taking so long?

- Reading the CSV
- Tokenizing
- Making the n-grams
- Counting the n-grams
- Writing to disk

So the first thing I would do is make a cleaner separation between the different steps, and ideally make it possible to restart half-way

## Reading the text

I would extract this to a different method. And from what I read ([here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/7510) for example) `pandas` reads csv-files a lot quicker than `csv`. If the reading of the csv only takes 1 minute of the 2 days, this might not be an issue, but I would do something like this:

```
def read_text(filename):  # you could add **kwarg to pass on to the read_csv
    df = pd.read_csv(filename) # add info on file encoding etc
    message = df['message'].str.replace(r'[\.]{2,}', r". ")  # http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html
    message = message.str.replace(r'([\.,;!?])([A-Z])', r'\1 \2')

    messame = message.strip()
    sentences = message.apply(nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize)
    return ' '.join(sentences.appy(' '.join))
```

You can even do this in chunks, and  `yield` instead of return the sentences to make it a generator, potentially saving on memory

Is there a specific reason you join the sentences after the `sent_tokenize` because I find this in the documentation

> The Treebank tokenizer uses regular expressions to tokenize text as in Penn Treebank. This is the method that is invoked by word_tokenize(). It assumes that the text has already been segmented into sentences, e.g. using sent_tokenize().

So you would call it like this:

```
text = read_text(csv_file)
with open(text_file, 'w') as file:
    file.write(text)
print('finished reading text from file') # or use logging
```

## Tokenizing

stays rougly the same

```
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
print('finished tokenizing the text')

def save_tokens(filename, tokens):
    # save the list somewhere, either json or pickle, so you can pick up later if something goes wrong
```

## making the n-grams, counting and writing them to disk

Your code contains a lot of boilerplate which does the same thing with just a different function or filename, so instead I abstract this away in a list of tuples containing the name, the function to get the bigrams to count them and the filename to save

```
ngrams = [
    ('bigrams', nltk.bigrams, collections.Counter, 'bigrams.csv'),
    ('trigrams', nltk.trigrams, collections.Counter, 'quadgrams.csv'),
    ('quadgrams', nltk.collocations.QuadgramCollocationFinder.from_words, parse_quadgrams, 'quadgrams.csv'),
]
```

If you want to count how much items are in a list, just use `collections.Counter` instead of making an (expensive) `collection.OrderedDict` on each item. If you want to do the counting yourself, better to use tuples than `OrderedDict`. You could also use  `pd.Series.value_counts()`

```
def parse_quadgrams(quadgrams):
    return quadgrams.ngram_fd #from what I see in the code this dict already contains the counts

for name, ngram_method, parse_method, output_file in ngrams:
    grams = ngram_method(tokens)
    print('finished generating ', name)
    # You could write this intermediate result to a temporary file in case something goes wrong
    count_df = pd.Series(parse_method(grams)).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': name, 0: 'count')
    # if you need it sorted you can do this on the DataFrame
    print('finished counting ', name)
    count_df.to_csv(output_file)
    print('finished writing ', name, ' to file: ', output_file)
```